# Function that stops all other functions in python

Tags: python, function, break

I would like to have a function that stops other functions.

```
def fun1():
    while True:
        print(1)

def fun2():
    while True:
        print(2)

def fun3():
    while True:
        print(3)

fun1()
fun2()
fun3()

def breakAll():
    #some code that stops all three functions
```

I would be very happy if anyone told me how to do that. If you need additional info, ask.
Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: quit() exits everything.

Comment: it looks like only fun1() will get called unless you have multiple processes. whats your current output?

Answer (score 0):

import sys

and place sys.exit() #place the function inside the parentheses

Comment: that works for me in most cases just make sure there are no processes being executed from the function when you stop it

Answer (score 0):

This thing will eventually lead you to infinite loop with no end. when you are calling `func1()` it is starting a loop and when it's completed then and only then `func2()` will start executing.

You can not run two functions parallel. If you want to execute two functions simultaneously then use multi-threading, you can control the threads with main threads. but with single main thread thing you want is not possible